# Is there a way to allow users to change their Active Directory password with Django

Tags: python, django, active-directory

I'm setting up a simple django webpage that helps users to update/change their Active directory password

We get a-lot of requests from users to reset their domain passwords(Active directory), in which we as the Administrators log in to the AD tool and reset their passwords, sharing with them over the call or email,

I wanted to create a simple Django website the links to the AD in which the user resets their password by themselves

Comment: That's a very broad question. I think you'll need to work with something like the [ldap library](https://www.python-ldap.org/en/latest/reference/ldap.html) for that, in particular the method `LDAPObject.passwd_s`. Do keep in mind that if you don't implement this well, you may allow users to reset the password for other users, with all it's implications. Be absolutely sure that this cannot happen however you end up implementing this.